# C# curiosity switching numbers

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C#, and learns mostly by solving "beginner problems" from different sites.
Most such sites have this 'Write a program which takes 2 numbers and switch them' and also their solution is something like:
`temp = number1;
number1 = number2;
number2 = temp;`

But I recently learned that this: `(number1, number2) = (number2, number1);` works just the same but without the third temp variable. So my question is, why? Why is this`(number, number2) = (number2, number);` not the same as `number = number2 number2, number;`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: `(number1, number2)` is a *named tuple*, you create one *instance* from another.

Comment: Your second example isn't c#. It wouldn't compile.

Comment: The compiler will generate the temp variable for you, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(number1, number2) = (number2, number1)

actually uses 4 number variables.

Left and right are structs, each containing two variables.

As such, hat happens is:

- The left side is allocated new.
- Then both variables are copied into the new space.

Leaving deatails aside:
Where your old logic used 3 variable spaces, the new logic uses 4.

This is invisible for you because you do not use named spaces for the struct or (if you would do that) you would assume that you only use 2 variables (which makes sense from a logical point of view from the programming language, but on a deeper level as those structs are variable containers of 2 variables each, you actually use now 4 spaces).

THAT SAID: the new syntax is likely faster too, because while the 3 variable trick is nifty, it creates multiple linear instructions while copying 2 variables CAN be palatalized by a CPU. This is getting into micro optimizations, though.

In a quiz my answer would be "ok, now without implicit structs", and adding structs forbidden to the query because it bypasses the logical problem you are supposed to show you understood.

Comment: Actually, if you decompile the output you'll see that the C# compiler will actually optimise `int a = 1; int b = 2; (a, b) = (b, a);` to `int a = 1; int b = 2; int num = a; a = b; b = num;` which only uses a single temp (and is pretty similar to hand-rolled code).

Comment: There's some discussion about this optimisation here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1656

Comment: Yes, but that is actually runtime optimization - I focus more on the logical part in my answer. Still a good point ;)

Comment: @TomTom I assume you meant to say "compile time optimization", since it's done by the C# compiler (not the JIT compiler)...